# How to launch a link in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to launch a URL link in ElevatedButton but it doesn't work if I press the button it does not do anything, is there a different thing that works with ElevatedButton or should I write a different label

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyAppThree extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyAppThree({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MyAppThreeState();
}
class _MyAppThreeState extends State<StatefulWidget> {
_launchURL() async {
    const url = 'https://www.youtube.com/';
    final uri = Uri.parse(url);
    if (await canLaunchUrl(uri)) {
      await launchUrl(uri);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        title: const Text(''),
      ),
      body: Container(
            child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
                   ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: _launchURL,
                child: Text(
                  'TAG Here',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),
                ),
                style: ButtonStyle(
                  backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                      const Color.fromARGB(255, 55, 55, 55)),
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: Did you setup android manifest and info.plist file for Url_launcher?

Answer (score 0):

Starting on Android 11 (API 30), you must add a  element in the Android manifest as a child of the root element:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.yourapp">

<queries>
  <!-- If your app checks for https -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
  </intent>

</queries>

/* rest of the manifest */

</manifest>
```